# Como fazer para o Line Chart ficar com a base zero

Tags: google-charts

Meu line chart está começando do -5, gostaria que a base ficasse em 0, alguém sabe qual configuração usar?

[image: Chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver, adicionei isso aqui nas options.

```
vAxis: {
            minValue:0,
            viewWindow: {
                min: 0
            }
        }
```